# In-place modification of a vector member variable through a vector of user-defined class elements

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Using Visual Studio C++ 2019

Why does this fail...

```
std::vector<Cell> cells{ 9 };
std::vector<Cell*> cells_copy;
for (Cell& cell : cells)
    cells_copy.push_back(cell);
```

...while this works?

```
std::vector<Cell> cells{ 9 };
std::vector<Cell*> cells_copy;
for (Cell& cell : cells)
    cells_copy.push_back(&cell);
```

What I am seeing is that `cells_copy` is a vector of pointers to user-defined `Cell` objects.
The range for loop iterates through cells, a vector of `Cell` objects, providing a reference variable (`Cell& cell`) to each element of cells.

The address-of operator on `cell` (a reference variable) returns the (`Cell*`) pointer to `push_back` onto the `cells_copy`?  I don't get it.

The idea is that I have a `vector` of user-defined (`Cell`) objects, each of which contains a `vector<int>` member variable, called `m_candidates`.

I would like to take a subset of this `vector<Cell>` collection and modify the `m_candidate` variables, in-place, of each cell.  I figured building a vector of pointers would do the trick, and it is actually working, but I don't understand why..

Any thoughts thoughts / alternatives are appreciated.

Comment: `Why does this fail...` Describe "fail" in more detail. Why do you think it fails? How does it fail? How does it behave? What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are confused with:

```
for (Cell& cell : cells)
     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

vs

```
cells_copy.push_back(&cell);
                     ^^^^^
```

In the first one, `Cell& cell`, you are declaring `cell` as a reference. What that mean is anything that you do with the `cell`, will be applied to the original cell in your vector. However, when you attempt to pushback `cell` into `vector<Cell*>`, `cell` itself is considered an `Cell` object, not a pointer.

Whereas the second one, `&cell` is applying the address-of operator to `cell`, which returns a pointer to that object. This is the reason why your `vector<Cell*>` allows you to pushback `&cell` into it.

---

In terms of modifying the original `vector` in place, you don't really need to build a `vector<Cell*>`, you could just do it in that for loop directly.

In fact, it is dangerous to make a vector of pointer to each item first, as if you increase the size of the original vector, it could reallocate the objects in the original vector, and make the pointers you created pointing to garbage values.

[Demo of printing garbage values](https://replit.com/@Ranoiaetep/GreenyellowBraveDecagons#main.cpp)

---

If you do want to store some items in the original vector, it is better to store the indices, then you can modify the original vectors like:

```
for(auto index : indices)
{
    original_vector[index].do_something();
}
```

Do know that you can still invalidate the indices if you insert new element in front of your original elements.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I get it.  Cell& cell creates a reference variable, but is automatically dereferenced when using it in the body of the for-loop.  So &cell is not the address of the reference variable, but the cell variable itself, as intended.

Comment: @spacecowboy you are correct, in fact a lot of people consider the reference variable as a syntax sugar of pointers, as they are mostly the same, except reference already dereferenced for you.